# Subclass references another subclass, accessible from the same getter/setter

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I am trying to achieve an OOP inheritance design in Java where, if I am presented with a subclass of `OrderTypeA`, and calling its `getOrderLines()`, it will return a collection of type `OrderLineTypeA`. Likewise, if I have an instance of `Order`, its `getOrderLines()` will return a collection of instance `Collection<OrderLine>`

I have tried the following, which does not seem to compile.

What I am trying to achieve:

**Proposed Architecture:**
[image]

Order

```java
public class Order {
    protected List<? extends OrderLine> orderLines;

    public List<? extends OrderLine> getOrderLines() {
        return orderLines;
    }

    public void setOrderLines(List<OrderLine> orderLines) {
        this.orderLines = orderLines;
    }
}
```

OrderLine

```java
public class OrderLine {
    private Order order;

    public Order getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(Order order) {
        this.order = order;
    }
}
```

OrderTypeA

```java
public class OrderTypeA extends Order {
    protected List<OrderLineTypeA> orderLines;

    @Override
    public List<OrderLineTypeA> getOrderLines() {
        return orderLines;
    }

    @Override
    public void setOrderLines(List<OrderLine> orderLines) {
        this.orderLines = orderLines; // does not compile
    }
}
```

OrderLineTypeA

```java
public class OrderLineTypeA extends OrderLine {
    private OrderTypeA order;

    @Override
    public Order getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    @Override // does not compile, technically not an override
    public void setOrder(OrderTypeA order) {
        this.order = order;
    }
}
```

Other solutions I have tried, includes omitting field declarations in the child classes, in order to hide the field in the parent.

Other ideas include overriding methods in the child, and casting return statements to the type of the child.

Thanks!

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: At the override in OrderLineTypeA, in the setOrder method, I get: 
`Method does not override method from its superclass`

In OrderTypeA, I get in the setter method, that the provided type is not the required type.

Comment: In setOrderLines() in OrderTypeA you try to assign a List of Type OrderLine to a list of type OrderLineTypeA. Assigning a sublclass its parent-type does not work. Correct me if I miss something

Answer (score 0):

I think at least one of the problems is here:

```
public class OrderTypeA extends Order {
protected List<OrderLineTypeA> orderLines;

@Override
public List<OrderLineTypeA> getOrderLines() {
    return orderLines;
}

@Override
public void setOrderLines(List<OrderLine> orderLines) {
    this.orderLines = (List<OrderLineTypeA>)orderLines; // does not compile
}
}
```

In setOrderLines() in OrderTypeA you try to assign a List of Type OrderLine to a list of type OrderLineTypeA. Assigning a sublclass its parent-type does not work.

Comment: The question is, how to achieve this? From what I understand OP wants to have  `List<OrderLineTypeA>` in this class, not `List<OrderLine>`. It would have to be declared as `setOrderLines(List<OrderLineTypeA> orderLines)` but then there's the problem with overriding method from parent - those will be different methods.

Comment: How about a cast? this.orderLines = (List<OrderLineTypeA>)orderLines; Also edited it in the answer

Comment: @Amongalen  `Order` will contain a list of `OrderLines`, whereas `OrderTypeA` will have a list of `OrderLineTypeA`.

Comment: Updated question, I forgot a newline after a codeblock.